# Changing the color of C# Properties in VS2015 names using Resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2015 and ReSharper. I am currently using the default Dark Theme the way it comes. However, I would like to make property names the color purple.

Please see [this video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs) for an example of what I am looking for. (56:37) or anywhere throughout the video.

**For example:**

```
var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

I want 'User.Identity' to appear in a color other than white.

I am assuming the only possible way to change the color of properties is by using ReSharper, but I can't figure out how in the Tools > Options > Fonts and Colors screen.

Comment: Just change the "Identifier" color under Fonts and Colors.

Comment: Thank you so much! So ReSharper isn't even needed for this.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway actually I am sorry, I don't think it is identifiers I want. It is whatever he has purple in this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Voso411Vs (56:37)

Comment: I believe it is Type names that I want to change the color of, but can't figure it out. Please see my updated post.

Comment: You might try "User Types".  I only have VS 2013 to look at now.  VS2015 may have other options.

Comment: It isn't user types, they already have predefined colors and none of them are set to white.

Comment: Ha, I came here looking for the exact same reason. He does a good job at marketing ReSharper. I might just buy it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature actually originates from ReSharper, but it is also coupled to the options dialog of VisualStudio. You need to enable ReSharper Options | Code Inspections | Settings. Afterwards modify the code (to trigger highlighting), and you can freely configure all the colours you want from the VisualStudio options. Btw, the entry for properties is 'ReSharper Field Identifier'.

[image]

Custom colours really come in handy in various situations, e.g., to separate real methods from extension methods, interfaces from classes (if not following naming conventions as for `DTE`), or value types from reference types.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, however I don't think enabling Color Identifiers does much. I still see ReSharper options under Options > Fonts and Colors regardless of whether that is enabled or not. The real question is what do you call the items in his video that appear purple (I believe they are Properties) and how exactly do I set them to purple?

Comment: The entries in Options | Fonts and Colors will always be there as long as ReSharper is installed. They are static and independent from other options. And also 'Color Identifiers' *does* something, it colors the identifiers :) Updating answer....

Comment: Wow! So simply enabling Color identifiers and not modifying anything afterwards did the trick since they already do color the identifiers in purple! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, having it to be modified was also surprising for me. Glad that it works!

Comment: Ugh. Wish properties were styled separately then fields. Properties are closer to methods then field access.